# URL mapping issue

Tags: java, url, tomcat, mapping

I have .war file named notebook.war . I'm deploying it using tomcat, putting it to the webapps directory and then starting tomcat.

There is a form with button

```
<form id="jform" method="post" action="/add">
```

and there is a servlet, mapped in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Create</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controller.CreateServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Create</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/add</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I launch tomcat, write localhost:8080/notebook in browser and go to the main page, then I go to the page http://localhost:8080/notebook/add.html through the link on the main page. Page http://localhost:8080/notebook/add.html contains that form and after submiting it I go to the http://localhost:8080/add instead of http://localhost:8080/notebook/add.

And even after I have remapped /add to /notebook/add in servlet mapping and form action tag, I go to the http://localhost:8080/add after submiting form.

How to make http://localhost:8080/notebook/add instead of http://localhost:8080/add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your `<form>` as

```
<form id="jform" method="post" action="add">
```

Notice, how  the `action` attribute doesn't have a leading `/` which is what making your client go to the *website's root* directory i.e. `localhost:8080/` and then `add`.

When you specify the `action` as `add`, it gets interpreted relatively to the current URL's *context root* i.e. `/notebook` and hence makes the client *post* to `/notebook/add`.